# is there any way to attach an ngClass to a pseudo-class?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I am trying to put a dynamic style on this element:

```
input[type=range].MPslide.pvd-slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track{}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't exist in my template so I can not place an [ngClass] on it.  At the moment I am doing this by setting a global CSS variable onInit() but this seems like a workaround.  What am I missing?  Is there a cleaner way to do this?  Thanks for any insights or suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a dynamic class on the container of your intended element (the component it's in) and do something like this

```
// my-component.html
<the-component [class.myClass]="myCondition"></the-component>
```

and

```
// my-component.css
:host ::ng-deep .myClass input[type=range].MPslide.pvd-slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track{
  // your dynamic style
}
```

you can read more about `:host` and `::ng-deep` from [Angular style special selctor](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

Comment: thanks a bunch, is there any other way to do this you know of without leaning on scss?

Comment: @imnickvaughn I updated the answer you don't have to use scss, I use it as default that's why I wrote it.